# Multiple Date Range Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm wondering how to create a Multiple Date Range Picker in JQuery. 
I have 4 weeks and I'm about to select 5 days per week.

- Week 1 has `date_from1` and `date_to1`.
- Week 2 has `date_from2` and `date_to2`.
- Week 3 has `date_from3` and `date_to3`.
- Week 4 has `date_from4` and `date_to4`.

I already have Date Range Picker working for 2 dates only. So when I select a date for `date_from1` (for example 2012-11-25) then `date_to1` will not able to select a date that is earlier than 2012-11-25, so this works fine.

All I want to do is when I select a date for Week 2 `date_from2` must be greater than `date_to1` of Week 1.

I need it to work like this:

- Week 1

  - Date From 1 = 2012-11-02
  - Date To 1 = 2012-11-07 // this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-02
- Week 2

  - Date From 2 = 2012-11-08 //  this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-07 which is the value of Date To 1 of Week 1.
  - Date To 2 =  2012-11-13 // this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-08
- Week 3

  - Date From 3 = 2012-11-14 //  this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-13 which is the value of Date To 2 of Week 2.
  - Date To 3 =  2012-11-19 // this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-14
- Week 4

  - Date From 4 = 2012-11-24 //  this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-19 which is the value of Date To 3 of Week 3.
  - Date To 4 =  2012-11-29 // this will not able to select dates less than 2012-11-24

The following JavaScript is inside `$(document).ready`. This will work only on two dates.

JS:

```
            var dates = $( "#date_from1, #date_to1" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", outputDateFormat : 'yy MM dd', changeMonth: true, numberOfMonths: 1,
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                    var option = this.id == "date_from1" ? "minDate" : "maxDate", instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ), date = $.datepicker.parseDate( instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
                }
            });
```

HTML:

```
Week 1
Date From1: <input type="text" name="date_from1" id="date_from1" value=""/>
Date To1: <input type="text" name="date_to1" id="date_to1" value=""/>

Week 2
Date From2: <input type="text" name="date_from2" id="date_from2" value=""/>
Date To2: <input type="text" name="date_to2" id="date_to2" value=""/>

Week 3
Date From3: <input type="text" name="date_from3" id="date_from3" value=""/>
Date To3: <input type="text" name="date_to3" id="date_to3" value=""/>

Week 4
Date From4: <input type="text" name="date_from4" id="date_from4" value=""/>
Date To4: <input type="text" name="date_to4" id="date_to4" value=""/>
```

Hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance.